# Draw box around Seaborn FacetGrid axes

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am unable to figure out how one might draw a black bounding box around each facet grid element.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = sb.load_dataset('tips')
g = sb.FacetGrid(df, col = "time")
g.map(plt.hist, "tip")
plt.show()
```

Gives:

[image]

I would like something like this:

[image]

I have tried using

```
sb.reset_orig() #after the seaborn import, to reset to matplotlib original rc
```

and various options on the axes themselves:

```
axes=g.axes.flatten()
for ax in axes:
    ax. # I can't figure out the right option.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: For example: `for ax in axes:
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('black')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('black')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('black')` only gives the X and Y axes as black - not the right and top. Hmm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why the spines are not `set_visible` by default but I was able to create this solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560829/seaborn-heatmap-with-frames) answer. Also, I get only two subplots using your code instead of 4 subplots as in the question. Perhaps this is a `seaborn` issue. I made your code concise by looping over the 4 spines.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
sb.set()

df = sb.load_dataset('tips')
g = sb.FacetGrid(df, col = "time")
g.map(plt.hist, "tip")

for ax in g.axes.flatten(): # Loop directly on the flattened axes 
    for _, spine in ax.spines.items():
        spine.set_visible(True) # You have to first turn them on
        spine.set_color('black')
        spine.set_linewidth(4)
```

[image]

**EDIT** (based on the comments below)

In the above answer, since you only want to change the properties of the spines (values) from the `ax.spines` dictionary, you can also just iterate over the values (spines) directly using

```
for spine in ax.spines.values():
```

Comment: Wow! @Bazingaa, that's awesome - bazinga indeed. I haven't seen the `for _, spine in ax.spines.items():` before - can you explain further, or provide a link where I could learn more? Thanks!

Comment: Here `ax.spines` is a dictionary. A dictionary have keys and values. To access the key and value pairs from a dictionary, you can use `.items()` which returns a (key, value) pair. Now the values are spines. Since you only want to modify the attributes (properties) of spines (values), you use `for _, spine in ax.spines.items()` to store only the spine (value). Since you don't need to do anything with the key, you use an underscore `_` since the key here is redundant. Check my edit in the answer

Answer (score 2):

Building on the full answer already provided, there is also a shortcut option using *despine=False* within the line of code to initiate the facet grid.  That said you'll need to change the style of the seaborn plot to *ticks*.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
sb.set(style='ticks')

df = sb.load_dataset('tips')
g = sb.FacetGrid(df, col = "time", despine=False)
g.map(plt.hist, "tip");
```

chart is below:

[image]